# How can I create a second row of headers with TextBoxes on it on my DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created a DataGrid and now want a second row of headers in the TextBoxes. I want it to look like this in the end. There are already similar examples on the site but they couldn't help me. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a Xaml code to implement it as shown in the example.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to add a `TextBox` to the header of each column:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="YourProperty" Binding="{Binding YourProperty}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="header..." />
                    <Separator />
                    <TextBox/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```